# How to make link not change color after visited without specific link's color

Tags: html, css, colors, visited

As title, After a link is visited it changes color. How to prevent it without specific color like this

```
a { 
    color: blue;
}
```

I also used this:

```
a:link {
   color:inherit;
}
```

but color change to black, and my original color is blue. I'm looking for a answer for any original color.

Comment: I guess `color: inherit` on `:visited` do not work here... I don't see a way other than setting a color to `a`

Comment: @PrestonM:I read your link but not my hope answer. In case using color:inherit; , the link's color will be changed to parent's color ( In my case is black) But parent'color is not same as a-tag's color before visited